# Proof that a subset of the Continumm has a first and last point

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

If $A$ is a nonempty, finite subset of the continuum $C$, then $A$ has a first and last point.

How do I prove this? I know I have to prove it using Induction, but I've been trying to prove this for days, I don't know how to do it. Please, could someone give me a few hints. I would beyond grateful.

Comment: Hint: The important things is that it is a finite totally ordered set. It does not matter that it is a subset of anything specific.

Comment: How do I prove that it has a first and last point though?

Comment: Using Tobias' hint, I'd say by induction on the number of elements of $A$.

Comment: Take a point. If it is largest, you are done. Otherwise, take a larger one. Repeat.

Comment: Induction step (for min): Take a set of $k+1$ points, and let $a$ be one of them. If $a$ is less than all the other points, we are finished. Otherwise, consider the remaining $k$ points. By induction hypothesis, this set has a minimum, and it is clear it is the minimum of the whole set of $k+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your induction step you need to suppose that every $n$-element subset of $C$ has a first and a last point, let $A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n,a_{n+1}\}$ be a subset of $C$ with $n+1$ points, and show that $A$ has a first and last point. Let $A_0=A\setminus\{a_{n+1}\}$; $A_0$ has $n$ elements, so it has a first element $a_j$ and a last element $a_k$. To complete the induction step, consider each of the three possibilities:

- $a_{n+1}<a_j$;
- $a_j<a_{n+1}<a_k$; and
- $a_k<a_{n+1}$.

Those are the only possibilities, and in each case you should be able to identify the first and last elements of $A$. When you’ve done that you’ll have shown that every $(n+1)$-element subset of $C$ has a first and last element; that completes the induction step, and by induction you’ll be able to claim that every finite subset of $C$ has a first and a last element.

Comment: @user1554862: You’re welcome!